# Convert number which are str from readlines to digits - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a "RSA Encyrpter && Decrypter" in python.

I got two files: "public.txt" and "private.txt", each of them consists of two lines with key pairs, for instance:

```
private.txt:
551
437

public.txt:
23
437
```

I want to read those lines from file and I'm doing this by using "readlines()" in python, please have a look:

```
def load_keys():
    n = open("private.txt", "r").readlines()[1].strip()
    e = open("private.txt", "r").readlines()[0].strip()
    d = open("public.txt", "r").readlines()[0].strip()
```

However, `n, e, d` are safed as string.. I'm trying to convert it to digit and for small numbers it's fine - I can use int() or long() but what if I want to use a number like `2972707374889996847812667774394680002419656866566098604400031599302998562192384595754389927039245776685876687343128498677629624892701967351358081915610133`?

How to read that number from a file and save as digit without limit?

Comment: Just int () cast them, how are you using cast ?

Comment: Ok but when I'm trying to perform encryption I got the following error: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python could handle it as int since PEP 237
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/

Comment: Seems like you trying convert it to C int. And it has limit. The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library could help you with huge numbers in C.
https://gmplib.org/